# Domain of bijectivity of function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity

There is a type of problems in my course in Complex analysis that I don't fully understand them.

> Given function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $f(z)=z^2$. You must specify the   analytic and bijective domain of this function.

I'll show you my solution, and then ask the question.

Since $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we can present it in the form of $z=x+iy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then it's easy to present $f(z)$ it in the form of $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

$$f(x,y)=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2iyx$$
So $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $v(x,y)=2yx$
Then we can check analyticity of function by substituting these functions into [Cauchy–Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) .

To check bijective of function $f(z)$ I used this theorem:

> Function is bijective if and only if it is invertible.

So I used [Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) to find point in neighbourhood of which the function is invertible.

For this problem I got that function has the inverse in neighbourhoods of all points except neighbourhood of point $(0,0)$ (Jacobian equal $0$ in this point)

So my question is

- I found properties of function $f(z)$ in the neighborhood of any point, but (as I think) I do not answer for the question of problem. Because knowing the properties in the neighborhood of any point does not give anything about the bijective domain. (You can see it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) in "Example" section.) I would be grateful if you would explain to me what to do in such a situation.

**Update**

**I took into account remarks in comments: I need a maximum domain of bijectivity.**

Comment: What does "the bijective domain" mean?

Comment: Being invertible isn't sufficient to guarantee that a function is surjective.

Comment: I mean a set of points on which the function $f(z)$ is bijection. I apologize, because English is not my native language.

Comment: Hint: If $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ then $z_2=\pm z_1$... To make it injective you must make sure that $-$ is not an option in your domain...

Comment: This question is a bit ill-posed. There are lots of domains where $f$ is bijective.

Comment: There is the problem of articles here. If the question asks for *the* bijective domain, and that is defined as a domain on which the function is injective, then there are many answers and so the word “the” is misplaced. If you amend the question to ask for *any* domain on which the function is injective, that makes more sense. It becomes much more interesting, and not much harder in this case, if you ask for a *maximal* such domain. (Articles sometimes get messed up in translation. And the Russian language doesn't even have them …)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints (I am assuming that you are asking for a continuous inverse):

1. Prove that for every $w \neq 0$ there are two points $z \in \mathbb C$ such that $f(z) = w$. We say, that there are two branches above $w$ (also note that $f^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$, indicating that there's something interesting going on around zero).
2. Try to construct an inverse function $f^{-1} : A \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C$ from some domain $A \subset \mathbb C$. This amounts, for every $w \in A$, to picking one of the two points from $f^{-1}(w)$. Observe that once you pick such a point, then actually some neighbourhood $U \ni z$ is determined by this choice, otherwise the inverse wouldn't be continuous.
3. By choosing bigger and bigger neighbourhoods, you can continue this process for some time. But you can't enlarge $A$ to whole $\mathbb C$ since this process will eventually lead you to the second branch and tell you to pick a different point in $f^{-1}(w)$ than the one you've picked initially.
4. As an example, set $f^{-1}(1) := 1$ and continue the inverse continuously along the curve $e^{i\phi}$, for $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. What happens when $\phi \to 2 \pi$?